# internal HDD with a bad sector - Can it be Saved?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, terminal

I have a 2.5 inch internal HDD which seems to have malfunctioned as the drive was being erased on a console.

I connected it to an internal HDD enclosure to allow the PC to start and then plugged it in.

It takes time, but it can be read on a Linux system, where it contains 5 partitions.

Default application Disks shows the different partitions inside with their size, it gives partition type unknown and contents unknown!

With the Terminal command `lsblk -f` it shows the drive letter with the partitions without any information.

With the command `sudo fdisk -l` the Terminal glitches when it gets to the device.

I thought the issue could be that the device requires a removal of the partition table using the command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=512 count=1` though the terminal doesnt do anything.

After trying to change partition on disks an error pops *"Could not stat device /dev/sdd - No such file or directory"* and the device is ejected

Is there any way i could be able to format or fix the drive since i do not believe its a hardware error?

Comment: Just to clarify, as you were in the process of wiping it, you are not interested in saving the contents of those partitions? 'recoverable' in the title can be interpreted several ways :)

Comment: yes, ill fix it

Comment: "I connected it to an internal HDD reader to allow the PC to start and then plugged it in."
HDDs don't need a "internal HDD reader" they can be connected to the mainboard. You article does not show any relation to the question asked in the title.

Comment: its a 2.5 inch hdd

Comment: To elaborate on @r2d3's question, what do you mean with "internal HDD reader"? Is it connected to a SATA port or is there some kind of USB adapter involved? Sometimes these can cause issues accessing drives that you won't have when using SATA.

Comment: @MiG I meant internal hdd enclosure, oh okay, ill check without it if it could work

Comment: Note that *"enclosure"* pretty much exlusively refers to an external one, so *"internal HDD enclosure"* is a bit ambiguous. I assume you mean 'bay'? And how it's fitted doesn't really matter, only the port it is connected to - is it a **SATA port** directly on the main board?

Comment: You should run a test with `smartctl -t long /dev/yourdevice` and check the results with `smartctl -a /dev/yourdevice`. The test can take a long time.